# Difference between IsMouseOver and IsHighlighted in WPF styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, ismouseover

As in the title, I was wondering what is the difference between `IsMouseOver` and `IsHighlighted` property triggers in WPF styles.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IsHighlighted` takes any input device (like keyboard) into consideration for showing logical focus. It is not a `DependencyObject` level dependency property, as far as I researched it is available only for following 3 controls in WPF:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted
System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.IsHighlighted
System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarDayButton.IsHighlighted
```

Comment: It should be noted that IsHighlighted does not target the root border of a MenuItem Style; attempting to achieve a mouse over highlight will only register if you're directly over the header component of the MenuItem. In order to achieve a mouse over highlight, IsMouseOver should be used instead. This is also a difference.